# Get cross references in sql and display it in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following cross reference tables about batery from smartphone

```
Tablebrand1

CODE    CROSSREFERENCE
A15     SAMSUNG A10
A16     SAMSUNG A20
A63     SAMSUNG A30

Tablebrand2

CODE    CROSSREFERENCE
X63     SAMSUNG A10
X64     SAMSUNG A20
X65     SAMSUNG A30

Tablebrand3

CODE    CROSSREFERENCE
TOP99   SAMSUNG A10
TOP98   SAMSUNG A20
TOP97   SAMSUNG A30
```

I need to make a table in mysql/php combining the 3 tables so that it brings me all the batteries for SAMSUNG A10

PHP TABLE for SAMSUNG A10

```
BRAND       CODE
Tablebrand1 A15
Tablebrand2 x63
Tablebrand3 TOP99
```

I hope I was clear. I am new to php and your help to unblock this problem would be very helpful.

Edit: So. if someone can help me how to express this in PHP it would be very helpful. Thank you

Edit2: I am trying with this code and it returns error 500

```
 <?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>brand</th><th>code</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
  function __construct($it) {
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
  }

  function current() {
    return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
  }

  function beginChildren() {
    echo "<tr>";
  }

  function endChildren() {
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
  }
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("((SELECT "Tablebrand1" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand1 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION 
(SELECT "Tablebrand2" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand2 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION
(SELECT "Tablebrand3" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand3 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10');");
  $stmt->execute();

  // set the resulting array to associative
  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v;
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: So, `Tablebrand1` is the name of the table (same for 2 and 3)?

Comment: Yes is a example. I take the opportunity to clarify that I cannot put everything inside the same table since there are other models of smartphones that carry the same battery

Answer (score 1):

With your current database design, I am not sure if there is a clean way of doing it. One hacky way would be to use unions and hardcode the table names in the select query, something like:

```
(SELECT "Tablebrand1" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand1 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10')
UNION 
(SELECT "Tablebrand2" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand2 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10'))
UNION
(SELECT "Tablebrand3" AS `brand`, CROSSREFERENCE as `code`
    FROM Tablebrand3 WHERE CROSSREFERENCE = 'SAMSUNG A10');
```

Again, this is definitely not a clean approach. And I'd highly recommend if you can modify your database design, as this is surely not scalable (assume you have 1000 brands, will you create 1000 tables for them and use lots of joins for needed queries?).

#### A possible schema (if possible):

- You can have a table `SUPLPIERS` which for each suppliers stores their ID, name, etc.
- A `PRODUCTS` table which contains battery info (code, reference, ...) and the ID of the supplier as the foreign key.

Hope this makes sense.

---

#### Edit: For the PHP part

You can use PHP's [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to connect to the database, execute the query and get its results.

A quick example from [W3Schools:](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

```
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests");
  $stmt->execute();

  // set the resulting array to associative
  $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Excellent and thank you very much. I had already tried to do something similar with UNION and the query works for me. My big problem is how to show that result in PHP

Comment: Sure, I'll try it then. Thank you very much

Comment: I just edited and added the php code that doesn't work for me